# Problema al usar useContext en React para la autenticación de roles: al verificar valor del rol, se obtiene undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy experimentando un problema al intentar utilizar useContext en mi aplicación de React para gestionar la autenticación de roles. Tengo un contexto llamado AuthContext que almacena la información de autenticación, incluido el rol del usuario. Mi objetivo es redirigir a los usuarios a componentes específicos según su rol.

Aquí está el código relevante de mi archivo *AuthContext.jsx*:

```
import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useMemo, useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export default function AuthContextProvider ({children}) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState("");

  //Memorizar la función login
  const login = useCallback(function (rol){
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    setUserRole(rol);
  }, []);

  //Memorizar la función logout
  const logout = useCallback(function (){
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    setUserRole("");
  }, []);

  const value = useMemo(() => ({    
    isAuthenticated,
    login,
    logout,
    rol: userRole,
  }),
  [isAuthenticated, login, logout, userRole])
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

/*Hook para consumir el contexto*/
// eslint-disable-next-line react-refresh/only-export-components
export function useAuthContext () {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

Y este es mi componente *EmotivaHomeUserRouter*:

```
import { useAuthContext } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import { EmotivaHomeAdmin } from "../home/structure/home/structure/admin/EmotivaHomeAdmin";
import { EmotivaHomeUser } from "../home/structure/home/structure/admin/EmotivaHomeUser";

export const EmotivaHomeUserRouter = () => {
  const { login } = useAuthContext();
  login("Administrador");
  
  const { isAuthenticated, rol } = useAuthContext();
  console.log("Rol: ", rol);
  return (
    <div>
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        rol === "Administrador" ? (
          <EmotivaHomeAdmin />
        ) : (
          <EmotivaHomeUser />
        )
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>Debe iniciar sesión para acceder a esta página.</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

El problema es que, incluso después de llamar a `login("Administrador")`, cuando verifico el valor de rol, obtengo undefined en lugar de "Administrador". Esto hace que mi aplicación siempre redirija a `<EmotivaHomeUser />`, incluso si el usuario debería tener acceso a `<EmotivaHomeAdmin />`.

¿Qué podría estar causando esta discrepancia entre el valor de rol y la llamada a login? ¿Hay algo en mi implementación de useContext o en el manejo de roles que me estoy perdiendo?